# C 2D array changing values on function exit

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've got a program that stores a series of arrays of size **4x4** in a linked list. After the function extending the linked list (void advance) returns, the contents of the 4x4 array change. why?

For example in this instance when inside the advance function

```
chain.next.board = {{3,3,3,3},{3,3,3,3},{3,3,3,3},{3,3,3,3}}
```

but once the function has returned

```
chain.next.board = {{3,3,3,3},{4200685,4210756,3,3},{3,3,3,3},{3,3,3,3}}
```

Am I going about passing the linked list in the wrong way? should I be using malloc? I'm not very familiar with pass pointers between functions in c.

```
typedef struct Link{
    int board[4][4];
    struct Link* next;
} Link;

int main()
{
    int board[4][4] = {{3,3,3,3},{3,3,3,3},{3,3,3,3},{3,3,3,3}};
    Link chain;
    board_copy( board, chain.board);
    advance( &chain);
}

void advance( Link *this)
{
    Link next;
    board_copy( this->board, next.board);
    //Process_move( board); //Where board is changed to reflect move made
    this->next = &next;
}

void board_copy( int from[4][4], int to[4][4])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            to[i][j] = from[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is that `Link next;`, in function `advance`, is local to the function. Once you leave the function, even if you leave a pointer to it (with `this->next = &next;`), anything can happen.

Comment: So the solution would be to initialise `Link next;` in main and have it passed through as an argument to advance?

Comment: Check out my answer for one possible solution. If you need clarification don't hesitate to ask on that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that `Link next;`, in function `advance`, is local to the function. Once you leave the function, even if you leave a pointer to it (with `this->next = &next;`), anything can happen.

I would do this:

```
void advance( Link *this)
{
    Link *next = malloc (sizeof *next);
    board_copy( this->board, next->board);
    //Process_move( board); //Where board is changed to reflect move made
    this->next = next;
}
```

Just don't forget to `free` the memory once you don't need it any more.

You also seem to have a call to `advance( &chain, 5);` in your code, but no function definition that corresponds.

Comment: Typically data in dynamically growing data structures like lists which are shared across functions must be allocated dynamically, i.e. with malloc(). (This is no critique of your answer which is perfectly correct  but just an add-on for the OP.)

Comment: @PeterSchneider Agreed.

Comment: am I able to call free on an entire list or must it be called on each pointer for which malloc was used?

Comment: You have to call `free` on each pointer that was dynamically allocated. You would have to loop through the list of boards and free each board, then move onto the next.